# TrendNET TE100 MP1U print server wont connect to my Canon S750

Tags: print-server

Following on from [my malware experience](https://superuser.com/questions/111246/are-msa-exe-and-ygh-exe-really-malware-and-what-else-do-i-need-to-do-to-clean-the) I'm working through re-installing software, peripherals and the like.

I've got a TrendNET TE100 MP1U print server which now can't see my Canon S750 printer. I've reinstalled the printer drivers on the PC and that works OK. I've got Sygate Personal Firewall running and added a rule to allow UDP connections on port 7303 as instructed by the TrendNET Control Center. Sygate also indicates that the Control Center is using ports 7305 for TCP and 30202 for UDP as well, so I've added them to the rule.

The print server recognizes and correctly identifies the printer but won't connect. I just get a "failed" method.

Also, when I try to add a printer (Control Panel > Printer and Faxes > Add New Printer) I can see the print server but it won't expand to show the printer itself.

So what do I need to do to get this thing working again?

The annoying thing is that I only installed the thing about 6 months ago and it was working fine before the re-install.

**UPDATE**

In the first instance I was able to get it working by manually re-installing the printer driver to the print server. However, the motherboard of my PC died and I had to replace the lot. In setting up the new PC I've managed to get into the same situation again and for the life of me can't remember how I managed to do this.

So while I try to remember I'm "reopening" this question in the hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by manually re-installing the printer driver to the print server.

Finally remembered how to do this:

Enter the name of the printer manually:

```
\\TE100-MP1U\S750
```

Then get a dialog saying that the correct drivers aren't installed. Click "OK" to install the drivers. Result - can now print.

Comment: I ended up abandoning this as it couldn't cope with being booted while the printer was off line. If the printer was powered up when the print server booted all worked fine, the other way round it just couldn't find the printer. Which made it somewhat useless.